# Amazon AWS RDS - SQL Server, more flexible scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, amazon-rds

I currently have an AWS RDS SQL Server Instance in place and the app that uses it see's peek usages during certain hours of the day. (9-10 and 6-7), during these times we are seeing a huge slow down in the DB performance. Now we can obviously scale up the backing EC2 instance but this seems like a large amount of wasted resource over the timeframe.

Is there any way to have a more flexible solution? IE Like elastic beanstalk allows us to add extra 'nodes' during peak times?

Comment: Is it read-heavy or write-heavy at 9-10/6-7?

Comment: Write heavy in the morning and read in the evening

Comment: RDS doesn't scale up and down quickly, you'll have to scale for peak or offload somehow. Caching in your application, or perhaps using dynamodb.